# When playing back sounds the more sounds that play at once the higher pitch and louder they seem to get

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

basically what the title says when i play back sounds using the basic

```
mySound= new Sound(); 
c = new SoundChannel();
c = mySound.play();
```

this is in a class that is being set to a mp3 for testing. I did have it generating sound but set it to a mp3 for testing the pitch problem. The more times it is called while the same sound is still playing the higher pitch it seems to become almost becoming louder as well. I thought that was the point of different channels? Is there same way to fix this with soundmixer or something? Thank you

Please don't downvote just because you don't understand what i am asking I see this happening way too often lately.

Answer (score 0):

mySound.play() is returning a new SoundChanel.

```
c = new SoundChannel();
c = mySound.play();
```

What you're doing here is assigning a new SoundChanel to c, juste after that, you assigne it an other new SoundChanel.

And assigning a new SoundChanel to c do not make the previous one disappear. It still exist (an thus playing), but c is not refering to it anymore.

Try this:

```
if(c!=null) // if c has previously be assigned a soundchanel (that might be playing), stop it
 c.stop();

c = mySound.play(); // assign new SoundChanel to c and play it
```

Comment: Well you're right that was sloppy of me but it still did not fix the issue

Comment: @RustyH you will have to declare the soundChannel (c) as a field in your class. You should post more code. The entire class perhaps. The pitch is not going up. Don't use words you don't understand. The volume is going up when the sound is played on top of previous copies of itself.